# Retrieve element margin if it's 'auto'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

Hi I'm trying position new dom element same as old one, and then hide old one so new would replace it: http://jsfiddle.net/jC33F/5/

Though if original element has margin:auto jQuery can't retrieve it.
Is there a way to be able to determine if element has margin:auto; ?

Edit:
Thanks to @Vibhu I came up with this http://jsfiddle.net/jC33F/43/ looks horrible :D And I'm not sure it will always work.

Feel free to suggest something better.

Comment: Not sure what existing answers do but I wonder how to do it without jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be crazy, but what about something like this for checking it an element has `margin: 0 auto` (cannot seem to find any other way):

```
var margin = $("#parent").css("margin");
if($('#parent').position().left*2 == ($('#parent').parent().innerWidth() - $('#parent').outerWidth())) {
  margin = "0px auto";
}

$("#positionable").css({
    position: $("#parent").css("position"),
    top: $("#parent").css("top"),
    left: $("#parent").css("left"),
    margin: margin
});
$("#parent").hide();
```

This code basically checks if the left value of #parent is equal to half the space between the 2 edges of its container. Worked for me in this case, might fail in other cases.

Comment: I came up with this http://jsfiddle.net/jC33F/31/ looks horrible :D And I'm not sure it will always work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with position absolute for #positionable

```
$("#positionable").css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: $("#parent").position().top,
    left: $("#parent").position().left,
    margin: $("#parent").css("margin"),
});
```

Comment: If original(#parent) element was centered, I want to make #positionable element centered too. It's impossible with position:absolute;

Comment: not impossible. you could set the left value to 50% and then set a margin-left value equal to half the width of the element

Answer (score 0):

Check if the returned margin is empty would work I guess

Be aware though, that if you do not set any margin property, this will still set `#positionable` margin property to `auto`

http://jsfiddle.net/jC33F/22/

EDIT:

I found this jQuery plugin that claims it can return the margin property from an element

http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/

Comment: looks like 'margin' is not supported. Though 'marginLeft' is '0px' for both margin:0px; and margin:auto;

Comment: @grisevg Right. Sorry about that, I forgot. Anyways, take a look at my edited post please.

Comment: Confidering your fiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/jC33F/39/ doesn't work. Parents margin:0px, but positionable is auto.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like any of these solutions. Checking the actual stylesheet is a solution. Another solution I came up with is to store the left/right values, temporarily change the left value and see if the right value still matches. If not, then it is set to auto.

```
var mLeft = el.css('margin-left');
var mRight = el.css('margin-Right');
el.css('margin-left',(parseInt(mLeft)-2)+'px');
var mRightChanged = el.css('margin-Right');
if (mRight != mRightChanged) {
    console.log('read element left/right margins as auto');
    el.css('margin-left','auto');
} else {
    console.log('read element left/right margins as their value');
    el.css('margin-left',mLeft);
}
```

Note, this solution is just for left/right margins.